# Yii2 - Page reload after ajax submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2, braintree

Here is the problem. I'm trying to implement an Ajax submission of my checkout form using the ActiveForm and the Braintree Hosted Fields. The JS script dealing with the Ajax it was already tested and it works just fine on other part of my website.

With this code, I can get on my controller the $_POST data and use that to proceed the payment transactions that normally.

**The problem is. My controller action keeps reaching the the render point on the end of the script. Which makes my page reload.**

I'm wrong or can i assume that in this context the return would never be touch after the post submission? The request goes to the controller, do its things, return as response to the view and nothing more should happen.

Following I'm posting the relevant parts of the process. 
I would appreciate a lot if you could give a help on that.

The controller:

```
  public function actionCheckout() {

    $checkoutForm = new CheckoutForm();
    $countriesList = $checkoutForm->countriesList();

    $brainConfig = new BrainHelper();
    $clientToken = $brainConfig->clientToken;

    if ($checkoutForm->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $checkoutForm->validate()) {
      $checkoutForm->value = BrainHelper::$boxPrice * $checkoutForm->quantity;
      $_POST  = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
      $nonce = $_POST["payment_method_nonce"];
      $brainHelper = new BrainHelper();
      $result = $brainHelper->registerPayment($nonce);

      if ($result->success) {
        $this->saveClientPurchaseDataToDB($_POST, $checkoutForm->value);
        BrainHelper::settlePayment($result->transaction->id);
      } else { // In this case, the transaction wasn't authorised by Braintree. Such a pity!
        // So let's communicate the bad news.
      }
    }
    return $this->render('checkout', ['model' => $checkoutForm, 'clientToken' => json_encode($clientToken), 'countries' => $countriesList]);
  }
```

The view:

```
<div class="checkout">
  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => $model->formName(), 'enableClientValidation'=> true]);?>
      <?= $form->field($model, 'first_name')->textInput(['placeholder' => Yii::t('checkoutForm','First Name')])->label(false) ?>
      <?= $form->field($model, 'last_name')->textInput(['placeholder' => Yii::t('checkoutForm','Last Name')])->label(false) ?>
      <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['placeholder' => Yii::t('checkoutForm','Email')])->label(false) ?>
      <?= $form->field($model, 'quantity') ?>
      <label for="card-number">Credit card number:</label>
      <div id="card-number"></div>
      <label for="cvv">CVV code: <span>(3 or 4 digits behind your card)</span></label>
      <div id="cvv"></div>
      <label for="expiration-date">Card Expiration Date:</label>
      <div id="expiration-date"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div id="submission-btn">
        <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('checkoutForm', 'Submit')) ?>
  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>

<?php $script = <<< JS
  $('form#{$model->formName()}').on('beforeSubmit', function(e) {
    var \$form = $(this);
    $.post(
      \$form.attr("action"),
      \$form.serialize() // serialize yii2 form
    );
    $(\$form).trigger("reset");  // cleans the form
    return false;
  });
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having a little bit of a hard time parsing your question, but I'm also not crazy strong with Yii. It seems like you aren't ever returning from inside your if(post) block. You could stick the return render inside an else block. Is this what you are asking? Can you clarify?

Comment: On my controller action I already tried to only render the view if my $_POST were unset. But still, the same thing. My stronger bet is something happen with braintree api to always refresh the view. I will try to provide more informations about the braintree implementation soon.

Comment: I would look at your rendered HTML and verify that `$('form#{$model->formName()}')` is returning the correct value and matches the id in the form.